# Mapbox GL set opacity of symbol layer

Tags: javascript, opacity, mapbox-gl-js

I have a symbol layer displaying text on a mapbox map and I am looking for a way to change the opacity of the text.

```
this.map.addLayer({
        "id": "symbols",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "source_circleCurrentGpsCircle",
        "layout": {
          "text-font": ["Open Sans Regular"],
          "text-field": '{title}',
          "text-size": {
            stops: [
              [0, 0],
              [22, metersToPixelsAtMaxZoom * 2]
            ],
            base: 2
          }
        },
        "paint": {
          "text-color": "#00FF00"
        }
      });
```

I tried a few things like the following

```
this.map.setPaintProperty('symbols', 'symbol-opacity', .6);
```

I think I just need the correct property name.  Is it possible to set a class for the symbol?  I could adjust the opacity easily that way.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  It turns out to be the text-opacity property, not symbol-opacity.  Seems obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

To change the opacity on a label from a symbol type layer use the `text-opacity` property. [Here's the documentation.](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-text-opacity)

**Example:**

```
this.map.setPaintProperty('layer_name', 'text-opacity', .6);
```